# How do i keep the self timer selected with the Nikon D5600?

Tags: camera-settings, nikon-d5600, self-timer

This is really very annoying. If i set the release mode to timer and take a photo, the release mode reverts back to single shot. And i have to set it to timer mode again each time i want to take another shot.

When i know ,  i am going to be shooting all my photos in timer delay mode, i still have to turn it back to timer delay , before every shot. Is this common for all Nikon cameras ? How about other DSLRs?

Am i missing something in the settings ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can do with the camera. It's very maddening, I know.

However, there is a workaround: use an external intervalometer that allows you to set the delay after pressing the shutter release. You rely on the intervalometer itself, rather than the camera's timer delay.

There are several choices of wired intervalometers available for little money.

Comment: This seems like such a stupid behaviour and there does not seem to be any reason to program the camera in such a way. This seems like one of those things, that has been deliberately programmed to make the lower end cameras worse off, so that people will have incentive to buy higher end cameras. Unless, this behaviour is common across all brands and price ranges ?

Comment: This is most likely not intentionally programmed to make the lower end cameras worse off. On the higher-end models, the self-timer is one of the settings on the "drive mode" dial, along with CL (cont. high speed), CH (cont. low speed), Q (quiet), and MUP (mirror-up). And this goes back a long way on their high end DSLR lineup, with the physical drive mode dial. Nikon tends to reuse most ofmtheir firmware code amongst cameras. Having a drive mode such as self-timer be a stored user setting on a low-end camera, when it isn't one on their high-end model, is probably too much of a code change...

Comment: ... for them to want to support in their common firmware lineup. Now that might sound like a point supporting the "purposely hobbled low-end functionality", but here's the counterpoint: drive modes are menu items on the Z7 as well, and it behaves exactly like your camera. I seriously doubt they intentionally hobbled that camera as a low-end model. More likely, they are very conservative with their firmware source code, and such a change in behavior would require extensive testing across all their model lineups (including models that are in support only) (and they _really_ don't want to ...

Comment: ... spend time or money testing old models that aren't bringing them any income). So I don't think it's deliberate, just more of a cost-avoidant thing.

Comment: But how come the other setting you mentioned on the "drive mode" dont behave like this ? The CL, CH and Quiet mode if selected, stay selected for every shot. It is only the Timer mode which has to be set for every shot. I guess you are saying, that it has been historically this  way and has not merited the attention/testing/ programming required to change it ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake. The Z7 stays in self-timer mode, unless the camera goes to sleep. When you wake it up, it's not in self-timer mode. Im not sure how the other drive modes acts after it goes to sleep. So I guess that just lends itself to... software is hard? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Cool, cool. The current workaround i am using is the remote photography through snapbridge app. But that app has got its own long list of bugs and maddening annoyances